# Prevent the same repeated n times digit in XSD Schema validation

Tags: xml, validation, xsd

The overall goal is to prevent the same repeated digit in the US telephone numbers.
See the following sample data:

- 0000000000 - not legit
- 7777777777 - not legit
- 9549867899 - legit
- 3051234567 - legit

I am trying to use regex pattern in the XSD validation.
In particulary, a negative lookahead approach.
Unfortunately, the XML Schema (XSD) regexes are limited.
The following regex **`^(?!(\d)\1{9,})`** does the job everywhere else, but  is not working in an XSD schemas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XSD Schema has its own fairly restricted regex dialect which does not include lookahead.

The only way I can think of doing this is the rather clumsy

```
0[0-9-[0]]|1[0-9-[1]]|2[0-9-[2]]|3[0-9-[3]]|....
```

which succeeds only if the string contains a pair of unlike digits.

Comment: I don’t understand why the correct phone # is failing the validation based on the proposed solution.

Running custom validation engine Saxonica 9.4.0.6 Validator...

Validation error at /root[1]/r[1]/ANI[1] on line 8 column 24 of ANIZeros.xml:
  The content "3051234567" of element <ANI> does not match the required simple type. Value
  "3051234567" contravenes the pattern facet "0[0-9-[0]]|1[0-9-[1]]|2[0-9-[2..." of the type
  of element ANI (See http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-2/#cvc-datatype-valid clause 1)

Comment: Java built-in Validation (Xalan Java 2.7.0).
file:///d:/Temp/QuickWins/IDT/ANIZeros.xml:8,24: (Error) cvc-pattern-valid: Value '3051234567' is not facet-valid with respect to pattern '0[0-9-[0]]|1[0-9-[1]]|2[0-9-[2]]|3[0-9-[3]]|4[0-9-[4]]|5[0-9-[5]]|6[0-9-[6]]|7[0-9-[7]]|8[0-9-[8]]|9[0-9-[9]]' for type '#AnonType_ANI'.
file:///d:/Temp/QuickWins/IDT/ANIZeros.xml:19,24: (Error) cvc-pattern-valid: Value '0000000000' is not facet-valid with respect to pattern '0[0-9-[0]]|1[0-9-[1]]|2[0-9-[2]]|3[0-9-[3]]|4[0-9-[4]]|5[0-9-[5]]|6[0-9-[6]]|7[0-9-[7]]|8[0-9-[8]]|9[0-9-[9]]' for type '#AnonType_ANI'.

Comment: Sorry, XSD regexes are implicitly anchored so you need to add .* (or [0-9]*) at the start and end of the pattern.

Comment: @MichaelKay that's very clever. I was thinking it couldn't fix the total number of digits (because the number of digits before and after the unlike digits are related), but of course you can just do that with an explicit length facet.

Comment: Java built-in Validation (Xalan Java 2.7.0).
file:///d:/Temp/QuickWins/ANIZeros.xml:8,24: (Error) cvc-pattern-valid: Value '3051234567' is not facet-valid with respect to pattern '.*0[0-9-[0]]|1[0-9-[1]]|2[0-9-[2]]|3[0-9-[3]]|4[0-9-[4]]|5[0-9-[5]]|6[0-9-[6]]|7[0-9-[7]]|8[0-9-[8]]|9[0-9-[9]].*' for type '#AnonType_ANI'.
file:///d:/Temp/QuickWins/ANIZeros.xml:19,24: (Error) cvc-pattern-valid: Value '0000000000' is not facet-valid with respect to pattern '.*0[0-9-[0]]|1[0-9-[1]]|2[0-9-[2]]|3[0-9-[3]]|4[0-9-[4]]|5[0-9-[5]]|6[0-9-[6]]|7[0-9-[7]]|8[0-9-[8]]|9[0-9-[9]].*' for type '#AnonType_ANI'.

Comment: Thanks to Michael Kay idea the following pattern does the job: `<xs:pattern value=".*(0[0-9-[0]]|1[0-9-[1]]|2[0-9-[2]]|3[0-9-[3]]|4[0-9-[4]]|5[0-9-[5]]|6[0-??9-[6]]|7[0-9-[7]]|8[0-9-[8]]|9[0-9-[9]]).*"/>`